# Unusual behavior of Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following code in C#:

```
public int AddSynonymBL(String[] syns, String word, User user)
{
    int dismissedCounter = 0;
    foreach (var item in syns)
    {
        BusinessLayerStatus.StatusBL res = this.dataAccess.AddSynonymDA(item.Trim().ToLowerInvariant(), word.Trim().ToLowerInvariant(), user);
        if (res == BusinessLayerStatus.StatusBL.SynonymNotAdded)
            ++dismissedCounter;
    }
    int numberOfFailures = dismissedCounter;
    return numberOfFailures;
}
```

And the following code is for `AddSynonymDA` method:

```
internal BusinessLayerStatus.StatusBL AddSynonymDA(string synonym, string word, User user)
{
    try
    {
        Synonym newSyn = new Synonym()
        {
            Meaning = synonym
        };
        //The following if means that the searched word does not exist int the Searched table
        if (this.context.Users.Where(a => a.Mail.Equals(user.Mail)).FirstOrDefault().Searcheds.Where(b => b.RealWord.Equals(word)).Count() == validNumberForKeyValues)
        {
            this.context.Users.Where(a => a.Mail.Equals(user.Mail)).FirstOrDefault().Searcheds.Where(b => b.RealWord.Equals(word)).FirstOrDefault().Synonyms.Add(newSyn);
            this.context.SaveChanges();
            return BusinessLayerStatus.StatusBL.SynonymAdded;
        }
        else
            return BusinessLayerStatus.StatusBL.SynonymNotAdded;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionAction(ex);
        return BusinessLayerStatus.StatusBL.SynonymNotAdded;
    }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework. I have a table which contains an Id, a word column. Both of them together have unique key constraint in the database. My `main` code is as follows:

```
public static void Main()
{
    EngineEntities context = new EngineEntities();
    BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
    String[] s = new String[] { "java", "DB" };
    Console.WriteLine(bl.AddSynonymBL(s, "Java", new User() { Mail = "media" }));
}
```

When I add a value which does not exist in the table everything is fine but when I add a value which already exists in the table, calling `this.context.SaveChanges();` in the `AddSynonymDA` method, always throws an exception which was for the previous first exception which caused the first exception and nothing is added to database even if they do not exist in the database. Why is that?

I get the following error which shows that Java already exists. The problem is that Java is for the first call, as the second call, I have passed `DB` not Java.

> {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_Searched'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Searched'. The duplicate key value is (java, 2).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Have you tried to create a new `context` after the first insert failed?

Comment: @hofmeister no, as I mentioned in `Main` method, I have just one context and I always use that. Is that wrong?

Comment: what is this method `AddNewWordToSearchedBL` ?

Comment: @media I'm not sure. Maybe the `context` keep the error state. Try to create a new one? I always use `using` with the context of the ef.

Comment: @hofmeister are you sure? because as I have learned, one instance of `EF` always should be used

Comment: Actually, creating a fresh instance for each separate transaction is fine. It was a few EF versions ago that db context instance creation was a bit slow, it's pretty fast with EF6+ so no reason to work with corrupted contexts.

Comment: @grek40 You meant the context can get corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have not set a column to be an Identity column in your database

In other words when you are inserting an entity you need a column to be automatically incrementing.
The way I do this is for example using SQL server:

```
ALTER TABLE [User] DROP COLUMN [ID];

ALTER TABLE [User] 
    ADD [ID] integer identity not null;
```

If you do not have an ID column already you do not need the first line.
After this, update your EF model in your project by deleting the User table and right clicking and Updating Model from Database and select the table.

So now when you insert new entries in you EF model, the ID column will be automatically incremented and you won't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

you must initially check whether the item exists or not, since you seem to have a unique constraint, then you should utilize the attributes of reference in your code .